# Web API Access denied error after Deploying in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC Web API application using Excel related DLL `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` When I run application from VS 2013, it is running under IIS express and I can send Post request to it successfully through RestClient But when I deploy this application to IIS, after sending Post request, it is giving me below error.

> Unexpected Error occured while serving your RequestSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I have Administrator privileges in my machine and I have given all permissions to folder which contains the code. I have also added user `IUSR` and given all access to the folder having my code.

Comment: Which IIS version are you using? Have you checked that the app runs as IUSR?

Comment: @JanneP : IIS version is 10 and OS is windows 10.
I don't know how to check if app runs as _IUSR_. Can you please share the process for same.

Comment: Check the application pool identity in IIS Manager: Application Pools->[YouAppPool]->Advanced Settings. A good MS article covering application pool identities can be found here: https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the App pool identity document shared by JanneP, I have changed application Pool identity from *ApplicationPoolIdentity* to *LocalSystem* and now issue got resolved and my application is working perfectly under IIS.
[image]